Communication with scanner interrupted error
I have successfully scanned with my CanonLiDE 400 scanner on Ubuntu on Monday Dec 24. I updated and upgraded the software today. It is currently Ubuntu 24.04. The scanner will no longer work. I have installed xSANE, Document Scanner, and NAPS2 successfully, and all there detect the scanner identifying it correctly, using the SANE drivers. The when I tell it to scan it gives an error message all roughly the same. In NAPS2 it says "Error Communication with the scanning device was interrupted."
The only option is to click OK. Basically there are no means to troubleshoot it. I have used the UBS cable supplied with the printer (USB-C to USB-A) and another USB-C to USB-C cable and using two different ports on the computer, but I got the same problem. I have tried restarted, unplugging and all that. I suspect it's a problem with Ubuntu and some permission regarding the USB port. This scanner has no on-off button; you just plug it in.
